# One word for the person who spreads positive vibes and is very spiritual in nature

Tags: single-word-requests, compliment

Can someone help me to describe in just one word a person who is spiritual and kind-hearted and who spreads positive vibes.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: http://thesaurus.com/browse/kind-hearted

Comment: @mplungjan - There are some good candidates in that list – like _gracious_ for one.

Comment: @J.R. does 'gracious' mean also 'spiritual'?

Comment: @Josh - I think there's some overlap. One definition of spiritual is "of a merciful or compassionate nature." In any case, it's going to be tough to find one word that encompasses all three characteristics – spiritual, kind-hearted, and spreading positive vibes – without spilling over into other areas as well. It's about as good a fit as anyone is likely to find; I was just trying to say that in a short comment.

Comment: [Insert central religious figure]-like could be understood as such, depending on audience.

Answer (score 2):

In Abrahamic religions, simply an *angel*, or a *saint*.

In a Hindu context, probably a *Mahatma* ("great soul").

In a Buddhist context, a *Bodhisattva* ("enlightened spirit").

Also a *gem*, a *pearl*, a *treasure*, a *flower*, a *godsend*, a *heavenly creature*, etc.

There are probably many more options, depending on your cultural background.

Answer (score 1):

I think *Guru* may come close to  your description:

> - A teacher and guide in spiritual and philosophical matters.

Source: [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Guru)

Guru:

> - As a noun the word means the imparter of knowledge.  As an adjective, *it means 'heavy,' or 'weighty,' in the sense of "heavy with knowledge," heavy with spiritual wisdom, "heavy with spiritual weight," "heavy with the good qualities of scriptures and realization," or "heavy with a wealth of knowledge."*
> - The word has its roots in the Sanskrit gri (to invoke, or to praise), and may have a connection to the word gur, meaning 'to raise, lift up, or to make an effort'.

Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guru)

Answer (score 0):

For the  “person who ... spreads positive vibes” part, consider *Pollyanna*. From [en.wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Pollyanna#Noun), a *Pollyanna* is “One who is persistently cheerful and optimistic, even when given cause not to be so. [Eg:] You call her an optimist, but I call her an obnoxious Pollyanna”.  (Of course, given that example, a *Pollyanna* is not always perceived as a source of “positive vibes” either.)

You might also refer to the person as *a regular [Mother Teresa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mother_Teresa)*.

Comment: The Merriam-Webster definition of _Pollyanna_ is "a person characterized by irrepressible optimism and a tendency to find good in everything." Whether such a person is tolerable for long stretches of time is somewhat beside the point. I think jwpat7 is right that _Pollyanna_ is the best answer to the poster's question. For philosophical (though not especially spiritual) optimism, consider _Dr. Pangloss_, in whose honor the adjective _Panglossian_ is named.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "rock".  A spiritual person who spreads good vibes can become a "rock" upon which one the who asks the question (and who seems like a sincere seeker) learns to rely.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello, Marshall. People often use the word 'rock' in everyday language for someone who is reliable, encouraging, pleasant ... no matter whether they show religious inclinations. Dictionary definitions accompany good answers on ELU.

Answer (score 0):

The word "soul" captures the spiritual angle while kind-heartedness and the spreading of positive vibes are the purview of *good* people. I don't think there's a single word covering the two concepts but perhaps it's sufficient to do a bit of DIY with the glue and make ... *"goodsoul"*. :o)

Comment: Hello, John. I've come across 'goodwife', 'goodsire' and 'goodman' but 'goodsoul', I agree, is a D-I-Y non-word, off-topic on ELU, which looks at researchable standard usage.